# Use model attribute as field parameter

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a folder and upload an image to in it. My model is similar to this:

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
    def code(self):
      syms = ['@','#','$','%','&','*','+','-']
      return ''.join(x+random.choice(syms) for x in [self.name[-2:],self.name[2:]])

    def make_folder(self):
        os.mkdir(os.getcwd()+'/XYZ/'+folder)

    def save(self):
        self.make_folder()
        super(XYZ,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    folder = property(code)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='HELP_HERE')
```

I've tried using `folder`, `self.folder`, `property(code)` but it says it isn't defined, how do I access this attribute? Is this the correct approach?

I've also set in the configs.py my `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`

Comment: where are you accessing `folder` or `self.folder` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more simple and understandable way to do this would be to avoid using the inner class function and doing something like this:

```
# Reference this function outside of your model class.
def xyz_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/xyz_<id>/<filename>
    return 'xyz_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.id, filename)
```

Then, on your models, reference the function in your `upload_to` field like so:

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=xyz_directory_path)
```

With your media config set up, this should work. There's a really nice and simple explanation about file handling [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html).

Comment: Could you explain why I can't access the attribute from within the class? I can in methods but it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend.